# AutoMapper .net 6.0 not in service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, automapper, .net-6.0, class-library

I downloaded automapper to a separate class library. I want to use this automapper in web api. I want to add automapper to services in program.cs, but it gives the following error.

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Hide Status Error CS1061
> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition of 'AddAutoMapper'
> and no accessible extension method 'AddAutoMapper' was found that
> accepts a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' (could be
> missing a using directive or assembly reference?) WebApi
> C:\Users\batu_\ Desktop\TaskProject\Backend\WebApi\Program.cs 8
> Enabled

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfCCG.png)

I downloaded automapper from nuget to map class library

Can't find AddAutoMapper in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfile));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a reference to: `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`